# How to assign two different methods to a single variable in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
Future<void> foo(int i) async => print(i);
Future<void> bar(double d, bool b) async => print(b);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var flag = true;
  var onPressed = flag ? foo(1) : bar(0.0, true);
  return Scaffold(
    body: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => onPressed,
      child: Text('Button'),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Problem:**

The method gets called during build process because I'm åctually calling `foo(1)`.
How to resolve this issue? I only want to get it done using one variable as shown above.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes but please post the reason for the same, in case you didn't understand the question, let me know.

Comment: and why to make it that complex? `onPressed: () => flag ? foo(1) : bar(0.0, true)`

Comment: @pskink I was originally using that, but now my functions are getting longer, there are around 7-8 arguments in both. So, I thought I code try something like that.

Comment: so do not use "inline" function: instead do `onPressed: _onPressed` and create a method `void _onPressed() { call your foo-bar functions here}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to do this. The closest thing that can be done is to change my variable to a method.

So,

Instead of

```
var onPressed = flag ? foo(1) : bar(0.0, true);
```

Use

```
void onPressed () => flag ? foo(1) : bar(0.0, true);
```